# Calculate Total Price based on Info in other Columns in SQL

Tags: sql, database

I'm using SQL Management Studio to create a database. I have a table named Items with the following columns:

```
ID    Product Name  Original Price     Discount Price   Shipping Price   Tax  Total Price
```

For now I am just adding arbitrary product names and original prices. What I want to do is have my Total Price column do something similar as Excel where, given an Original Price, a Discount Price, Shipping Price and Tax, I can create a formula in Total Price so that if any other prices ever change, the Total Price is computed automatically. I don't know how to do this, but I've tried to create a function and then call the function in my INSERT VALUES statement:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CalculateTotal()
RETURNS money;
AS

BEGIN
DECLARE @totalPrice int;
SELECT @totalPrice = ((Original Price - Discount Price) + Shipping Price) + tax
FROM dbo.Items
Return @totalPrice

END
```

Then I inserted the method:

```
  INSERT INTO dbo.Items VALUES('00000', 'Laptop', $200.00, $20.00, $4.99, $5.49,   dbo.CalculateTotal())
```

However, that did not work. The datatype I used for all the prices is the money data type. How can I calculate the Total Price? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may just need need to place `[]` around your column names to avoid confusing Management Studio.

This worked for me:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CalculateTotal()
RETURNS money
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @totalPrice int;
    SELECT @totalPrice = (([Original Price] - [Discount Price]) + [Shipping Price]) + tax
    FROM dbo.Items
    Return @totalPrice
END
```